# Convergence in distribution of random variable

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Defining $n$ with $n \in {\Bbb N}$, consider the random variable
>   ${X_n}$ for which:   $${\rm P}\left( {{X_n} =  - \frac{1}{n}} \right)
>  = {\rm P}\left( {{X_n} = \frac{1}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$$   Does the sequence of random variables converge in distribution? If so, find
>   the limiting distribution and show convergence.

I tried starting from the most familiar definition I had:  ${F_{{X_n}}}$ converges in distribution to ${F_X}$ if $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {F_{{X_n}}} = {F_X}$.
This seems simple, but I am not given the cdf ${F_{{X_n}}}$ and the only thing I tried writing from the information the question provides was that if ${\rm P}\left( {{X_n} =  - \frac{1}{n}} \right) = {\rm P}\left( {{X_n} = \frac{1}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}$, then $\int\limits_0^{ - \frac{1}{n}} {{f_u}du}  = \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{n}} {{f_u}du}  = \frac{1}{2}$ (I'm not sure this is exact, nor if it's useful).

I also tried sketching a graph of the areas before both ${ - \frac{1}{n}}$ and ${ \frac{1}{n}}$ and making each equal to $1/2$, and that didn't make a lot of sense to me. I'm certainly missing the point here.
Any inputs just as how to tackle it? Thank you very much.

Comment: There's a key thing you're missing in your definition of convergence in distribution: $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x)=F_X(x)$ "for every continuity point".

Comment: Clarification: "for every continuity point of $F_X$" @pedro alonso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that 
$$F_{X_n}(x)=\begin{cases}0& x<-\frac{1}{n}\\\frac{1}{2}& -\frac{1}{n}\leq x<\frac{1}{n}\\ 1& \frac{1}{n} \leq x \end{cases}$$

Consider $X\sim \delta_0$, with CDF

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0 &x<0\\1&0\leq x\end{cases}$$

We need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x)=F_X(x)$ for every $x\neq 0$ (continuity points of $F_X$). If $x<0$, for $n$ big enough, $F_{X_n}(x)=0$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x)=0=F_X(x)$. If $x>0$, for $n$ big enough, $F_{X_n}(x)=1$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}(x)=1=F_X(x)$, Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you for your help, really.

Comment: if you don't mind, I have some questions about it:
a)How do you get to/choose an ${F_X}$ like you did before performing the checks on the limits?
b) Do I just ignore the part of the original sequence where $x$ sits between $ - \frac{1}{n}$ and $ \frac{1}{n}$? c) How could you tell that the condition the questions states is actually $ - \frac{1}{n} < x < \frac{1}{n}$? The way it's written I would not be able to say that $x$ is between them like that.

Comment: a) this is kind of tricky. Sometimes is experience and sometimes a picture helps and sometimes is just computation. The key to note here is that as $n$ grows bigger, the support of $X_n$ gets closer and closer to zero. Essentially, as $n\to\infty$, $X_n$ seems to leave you with only a value it could take, which is $x=0$. A picture Can inform you about this. b) that’s the key of the definition of convergence in distribution: you only have to check for continuity points of the limiting distribution. For any $x\neq 0$, when $n$ is big enough, either $x<-1/n$ or $x>1/n$.

Comment: The fact that convergence in distribution definition allows us to forget about discontinuity points allows us to not care about what happens for $x=0$. c) we know that the condition must be written as $-1/n\leq x<1/n$ because the cdf must be right-continuous, so that’s just by construction. In the limit, the only number in that range must have $0\leq x<0$: no number has this property. Here you can see that in the limit the mass in that range moves to the part with $x\geq 0$, but not having to check what happens in discontinuity points allows us to not worry about it.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you